# Can I omit "which"+verb in a non-defining relative clause?

Tags: meaning, differences, writing-style

Which sentence below sounds better? Is there an incorrect/correct one? Is there a difference in meaning?
I tend to like the second one the most. To me, it has the same meaning as the first one but bit fancier, idk :P

1. The NIR had just been discovered: a type of radiation undetectable by the human eye.
2. The NIR had just been discovered, a type of radiation undetectable by the human eye.
3. The NIR had just been discovered, which is a type of radiation undetectable by the human eye.

Comment: No: 1 and 2 are not relative clauses but supplementary (non-defining) appositive NPs.

Comment: It's usual to put a descriptive noun phrase or relative clause immediately after the noun it modifies; in practice people can usually infer the connection, but some grammarians frown upon it. e.g. "The NIR, a type of radiation undetectable by the human eye,  had just been discovered."

Comment: Yes; I was just about to comment on the distancing Stuart mentions. Your versions are not ungrammatical, and sometimes shunting a non-defining appositive NP / relative clause to the end of the sentence is the better option. Here, it sounds rather literary. You'd need a pair of dashes (or brackets) to adjust your first example: << (1') The NIR – a type of radiation undetectable by the human eye –  had just been discovered. >>

Comment: No reason for extraposition from NP here; redo from start.

Comment: As an editor, I would say that all of those are incorrect. *The NIR, a type of radiation undetectable by the human eye, had just been discovered.* Or *The NIR, which is a type of radiation undetectable by the human eye, had just been discovered.*